# Python file manipulation

Tags: python, file, directory, pattern-matching

Assume I have such folders

```
  rootfolder
      | 
     / \ \
    01 02 03 ....
    |
  13_itemname.xml
```

So under my rootfolder, each directory represents a month like 01 02 03 and under these directories I have items with their create hour and item name 
such as 16_item1.xml, 24_item1.xml etc, as you may guess there are several items and each xml created every hour.

Now I want to do two things:

- I need to generate a list of item names for a month, ie for 01 I have item1, item2 and item3 inside.
- I need to filter each item, such as for item1: i want to read each from 01_item1.xml to 24_item1.xml.

How can I achieve these in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)) in an easy way?

Comment: What code do you have now?  This is not "write my code for me.com".  What did you try?  When you looked at `os.walk`, what did you see?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two methods doing what you ask (if I understood it properly). One with regex, one without. You choose which one you prefer ;)

One bit which may seem like magic is the "setdefault" line. For an explanation, see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault). I leave it as "an exercise to the reader" to understand how it works ;)

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import join

DATA_ROOT = "testdata"

def folder_items_no_regex(month_name):

   # dict holding the items (assuming ordering is irrelevant)
   items = {}

   # 1. Loop through all filenames in said folder
   for file in listdir( join( DATA_ROOT, month_name ) ):
      date, name = file.split( "_", 1 )

      # skip files that were not possible to split on "_"
      if not date or not name:
         continue

      # ignore non-.xml files
      if not name.endswith(".xml"):
         continue

      # cut off the ".xml" extension
      name = name[0:-4]

      # keep a list of filenames
      items.setdefault( name, set() ).add( file )

   return items

def folder_items_regex(month_name):

   import re

   # The pattern:
   # 1. match the beginnning of line "^"
   # 2. capture 1 or more digits ( \d+ )
   # 3. match the "_"
   # 4. capture any character (as few as possible ): (.*?)
   # 5. match ".xml"
   # 6. match the end of line "$"
   pattern = re.compile( r"^(\d+)_(.*?)\.xml$" )

   # dict holding the items (assuming ordering is irrelevant)
   items = {}

   # 1. Loop through all filenames in said folder
   for file in listdir( join( DATA_ROOT, month_name ) ):

      match = pattern.match( file )
      if not match:
         continue

      date, name = match.groups()

      # keep a list of filenames
      items.setdefault( name, set() ).add( file )

   return items
if __name__ == "__main__":
   from pprint import pprint

   data = folder_items_no_regex( "02" )

   print "--- The dict ---------------"
   pprint( data )

   print "--- The items --------------"
   pprint( sorted( data.keys() ) )

   print "--- The files for item1 ---- "
   pprint( sorted( data["item1"] ) )


   data = folder_items_regex( "02" )

   print "--- The dict ---------------"
   pprint( data )

   print "--- The items --------------"
   pprint( sorted( data.keys() ) )

   print "--- The files for item1 ---- "
   pprint( sorted( data["item1"] ) )
```

Comment: You're welcome. I just edited it slightly. Have a look. It may be less readable, but it may perform better (just a gut-feeling).

Comment: *Very important*: The above code contained a bug. If the item-name contained a "_" the code would break with "too many values to unpack" (I think that's the message it would give). I added a "maxsplit" param to the call to "split". This will prevent the error.

Comment: when you do 'items.setdefault( name, [file] ).append( file )' in your code shouldn't you be doing 'items.setdefault( name, [] ).append( file )' to avoid repetition?

Comment: Oops. yes. It must be... monday morning... ;)

Comment: Replaced the `list` with a `set`. Should be enough, and faster.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for pointing me to setdefault. It's good to just casually browse SO. You learn something every day :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that item names have a fixed length prefix and suffix (ie, a 3 character prefix such as '01_' and a 4 character suffix of '.xml'), you could solve the first part of the problem like this:

```
names = set(name[3:-4] for name in os.listdir('01') if name.endswith('.xml')]
```

That will get you unique item names.

To filter each item, simply look for files that end with that item's name and sort it if required.

```
item_suffix = '_item2.xml'
filtered = sorted(name for name in os.listdir('01') if name.endswith(item_suffix))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want to do, but here are some pointers that might be useful

---

creating filenames ("%02d" means pad left with zeros)

`foldernames = ["%02d"%i for i in range(1,13)]`

`filenames = ["%02d"%i for i in range(1,24)]`

---

use **os.path.join** for building up complex paths instead of string concatenation

```
os.path.join(foldername,filename)
```

---

**os.path.exists** for checking whether a file exists first

```
if os.path.exists(newname):
    print "file already exists"
```

---

for listing directory contents, use **glob**

```
from glob import glob
xmlfiles = glob("*.xml")
```

---

use **shutil** for higher level operations like creating folders, renaming files

`shutil.move(oldname,newname)`

---

**basename** to get a file name from a full path

`filename = os.path.basename(fullpath)`